# Sessions don't work on MAMP

Tags: php, session, wamp, mamp

I'm using MAMP, but I have a problem with session. My code works perfectly on WAMP, but doesn't work on MAMP and I don't no why. I looked the phpinfo but there are the same for the session between MAMP and WAMP.

PHP log file :
`[01-May-2012 12:18:28] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-    start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by     (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/index.php:7) in     /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/header.php on line 2
[01-May-2012 12:18:28] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/index.php:7) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/header.php on line 2`

Apache log file :
`[Tue May 01 12:03:29 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue May 01 12:03:29 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue May 01 12:03:29 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 01 12:04:11 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue May 01 12:04:24 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue May 01 12:04:24 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue May 01 12:04:24 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue May 01 12:05:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store`

Why they doesn't work ?

Thank you.

Comment: you have an apache log (MAMP/logs/apache_access_log ) which is devided between access and error logs. i'd have a look there. apache might give you an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here:

```
 headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Website/index.php:7)
```

in that line there is some output generated before you call `session_start()`. If you generate ANY output (even just a newline or something, whitespace, you name it) a header gets send and you cannot send another header for `session_start()`.

I doubt it has anything specifically to do with your *AMP.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a comment before, but that's work on WAMp so it's very strange ! But thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using MAMP for Mac.

I got the same error message you got.

I solved my problem by:

Instead of having your php on the head of the document.
Put the PHP on top before (doctype)

I did this and the code worked.

Also, make sure the (php) tag
is the first in the document. Leave no white spaces.

GL